# ChromeDriver has crashed

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

ChromeDriver not working.

**Terminal Output**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawler.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/lib/chromium/chromium is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

**Python Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver 
import pandas as pd 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/user/NoCopyrightSounds/videos")

user_data = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="video-title"]')
links = []
for i in user_data:
            links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))

print((links))
```

Chrome Version: 80 |
ChromeDriver Version: 80 |
Python Version: 3.5.6 |

What's the problem?

Comment: hi, check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t , it has the same error as yours.

Comment: Hey. Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are missing some capablities, try using following codes before opening chrome driver

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")

capabilities = options.to_capabilities()

driver = webdriver.Remote(\command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:40000/wd/hub', \desired_capabilities=capabilities)

driver.get('https:...')
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to place your driver and then pass the URI:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", chrome_options=chrome_options)
```